# Run several coroutines in a container deployed in OpenShift

Tags: kotlin, openshift, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I have the following Kotlin code deployed as a container in OpenShift:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module() {

    launch { consumeProductionGeneratingUnits1hTopic() }
    launch { consumeProductionLargeGeneratingUnits1hTopic() }
    launch { consumeProductionAggregateProdType1hTopic() }

}
```

Each of the coroutines is simply consuming from a kafka topic in an infinite loop:

```
fun runCoroutine() {
    val consumer = buildConsumer("topic")
    while (true){
        val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        println(record.toString())
    }
}
```

When I run this code locally, all three coroutines are started. However, when I deploy and run the code as a container in OpenShift, only the first two coroutines are started. It looks like OpenShift supports a maximum of two coroutines.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I have tried to reserve more cpu for the running pod, but it does not affect how the coroutines behave.

Comment: Are you using an old version of the coroutines library, or is your real `main()` method different from the one you posted? If the latter, please update to show the real coroutine scope you're using to launch the coroutines.

Comment: I have updated my `main()`. However, I have encountered a curiosity with your `yield()` solution: When the poll duration is set to 30 seconds, only two coroutines are launched. But when I set the poll duration to 5 seconds all three coroutines launches. Do you have any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention to the long timeout on the `poll()` call. The problem is that `poll()` blocks the thread by design. If you give it 30 seconds, it can block (not suspend!) for 30 seconds if there is no data available, and thus `yield()` won't be called during this time, so it doesn't give the thread the opportunity to go execute another coroutine. It might be better to use a `delay(5s)` instead of `yield()`, and use `poll()` with a timeout of 0 so you never block. `delay()` suspends so the thread is free during the whole wait.

Comment: I switched to using threads instead (i.e. one thread for each polling function), and the application seems much more stable now. Could I ask you to give a brief overview of the pros and cons of using threads vs coroutines?

Comment: It's hard to be concise. The main pro is that you can create many coroutines without thinking too much because they cost way less memory than threads. It's easier to size a thread pool appropriately (e.g. `Dispatchers.Default` / `Dispatchers.IO`) and then spawn coroutines without counting. Spawning too many threads could be counter productive, but using exactly as many threads as cores for CPU-bound tasks is easy with coroutines. Another point is coroutines are easier to follow compared to listener-based async code. They are also cooperative, which makes them more predictable.

Comment: The main con is that you need to be careful when using blocking code (they are not meant for that). You either need to replace blocking calls by async equivalents, or you have to offload them to some auto-growing pool like `Dispatchers.IO` - which makes the coroutines not much better than threads then. Another con to consider would be learning curve if you have no experience with them.

Comment: If in your case you simply need 3 blocking concurrent operations, you might get away with just threads. But if you have more, you would benefit from using coroutines for each concurrent polling, and dispatch them on less threads (using `yield` or `delay` to intertwine them - and more importantly a smaller timeout for the `poll()` call)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge, Joffrey! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that you're not using suspending functions, so these coroutines will just block the thread they are run on forever with their `while(true)` loop. Coroutines are designed to be cooperative, so you need suspension points to allow the threads to switch.

With the current implementation, if you're dispatching on a thread pool with only 2 threads, the first 2 coroutines will block them, and the third coroutine will never run. Some coroutine dispatchers use a number of threads that depend on the number of available cores, which would explain the difference in behaviour between your local machine (likely more than 2 cores) and the containers (likely 2 cores).

I cannot tell whether you're dispatching these coroutines on a thread pool with more than 2 threads, because you didn't show the coroutine scope on which you `launch` them (your code as-is shouldn't compile, unless you are using a very old version of coroutines with top-level `launch` without `CoroutineScope` receiver?).

#### Solutions

Of course you could allocate more cores to your pod, but that's just pushing the problem.

Another option is to use a thread pool with more threads, but that's also just pushing the problem.

A correct fix IMO would be to actually use async APIs converted to `suspend` functions. But an easier (quick) fix is to keep your code as-is, but just add a call to [yield()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) in the loop to make sure the thread is freed from time to time for other coroutines:

```kotlin
suspend fun runCoroutine() {
    val consumer = buildConsumer("topic")
    while (true){
        val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        println(record.toString())
        yield() // ensures we suspend to free the thread
    }
}
```